# Spring Security OAuth2 - multiple ResourceServer configurations

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

I have a Spring Security app that I want to be able to validate multiple tokens - I want to be able to pass an `Authorization` header with a bearer token from either Google or an internal service and have the backend try to validate with each service in turn.

My issue is that I only see the first (based on the lower `resource.setOrder(x)` x value).  In other words, I have 2 resource server configurations but it's only using the first one and not the second.

If I set google to 3 and the other to 4, the google token validation works find, but when I try to access `/` it is allowed and I see the Google filter work (`BTE for Google` in the output) but not the second one I have configured (`BTE for App`).

I'm trying to configure 2 ResourceServers like so:

```
   @Bean
    protected ResourceServerConfiguration googleLoginResources() {
        ResourceServerConfiguration resource = new ResourceServerConfiguration() {
            public void setConfigurers(List<ResourceServerConfigurer> configurers) {
                super.setConfigurers(configurers);
            }
        };

        resource.setConfigurers(Collections.<ResourceServerConfigurer>singletonList(new ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {

            ResourceServerTokenServices googleLoginTokenServices(OAuthProperties oAuthProperties, AccessTokenValidator tokenValidator) {
                LOGGER.info("Configuring Google ResourceServerTokenServices");
                GoogleTokenServices googleTokenServices = new GoogleTokenServices(tokenValidator);
                googleTokenServices.setUserInfoUrl(oAuthProperties.getUserInfoUrl());
                return googleTokenServices;
            }

            AccessTokenValidator googleLoginTokenValidator(OAuthProperties oAuthProperties) {
                LOGGER.info("Configuring Google AccessTokenValidator");
                GoogleAccessTokenValidator accessTokenValidator = new GoogleAccessTokenValidator();
                accessTokenValidator.setClientId(oAuthProperties.getClientId());
                accessTokenValidator.setCheckTokenUrl(oAuthProperties.getCheckTokenUrl());
                return accessTokenValidator;
            }


            class BTEG extends BearerTokenExtractor {
                @Override
                protected String extractToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
                    LOGGER.info("BTE for Google");
                    return super.extractToken(request);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
                LOGGER.info("Configuring Google ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer");
                resources.resourceId(oAuthProperties.getClientId());
                ResourceServerTokenServices gts = googleLoginTokenServices(oAuthProperties, googleLoginTokenValidator(oAuthProperties));

//                DelegatingTokenServices dts = new DelegatingTokenServices();
//                dts.addResourceServerTokenServices(gts);
                resources.tokenServices(gts);
                resources.tokenExtractor(new BTEG());
            }

            @Override
            public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                LOGGER.info("Configuring HTTP");
                http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                http
                        .cors().and()
                        //.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**").and()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/login/google").permitAll()
                        //.antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/login/google").hasRole("GOOGLE_USER")
                        //.antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                ;
            }
        }));
        resource.setOrder(3);
        return resource;
    }

    @Bean
    protected ResourceServerConfiguration appLoginResources() {
        ResourceServerConfiguration resource = new ResourceServerConfiguration() {
            public void setConfigurers(List<ResourceServerConfigurer> configurers) {
                super.setConfigurers(configurers);
            }
        };

        resource.setConfigurers(Collections.<ResourceServerConfigurer>singletonList(new ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {

            class BTEA extends BearerTokenExtractor {
                @Override
                protected String extractToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
                    LOGGER.info("BTE for App");
                    return super.extractToken(request);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
                LOGGER.info("Configuring App ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer");
                resources.resourceId("app");
                resources.tokenExtractor(new BTEA());
            }

            @Override
            public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                LOGGER.info("Configuring App HTTP");
                http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                http
                        //.cors().and()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/").hasRole("ASDF")
                ;
            }
        }));
        resource.setOrder(4);
        return resource;
    }
```

How do I make this work for both (or more, if needed)?

Comment: were you able to solve this issue ? I am in similar situation need help?